# When finish() should be called?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that calls second activity through an intent. After the second Activity is called I want to finish the first activity. Thus, I have the following code in `onStop()` method:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (shouldBeClosed) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my first activity is not closed. And I do not understand why?
Maybe I should put this code into `onPause()`?
But as I understand in this case, when activity loose focus (like after the call of a dialog) my activity can be closed.
So the question why this happens and how I can correct this behavior?

P.S. The variable `shouldBeClosed` is true. This is not the point.

**EDIT**

Here is the call of the second activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AcSpContextAssign.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt(Constants.KEY_FROM_ACTIVITY, Constants.FROM_AcSpNameCreate);
extras.putLong(Constants.KEY_SPID, spId);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I've gotten in the habit of finishing activities I no longer need immediately after creating the next one. I would think using onPause() or onStop() would accomplish this no problem.. How do you know it is not closed? How long does it stay alive?

Comment: If I press back button or simply finish second activity I see the first activity.

Comment: agreed, how do you know it's not finished? you can tell for sure by putting a breakpoint in `onCreate()`. after the `onStop()` code runs, you should see `onCreate()` called the next time you invoke the activity.

Comment: maybe setting flag to the intent would be better, look at addFlags, there is many flags as NO_HISTORY etc.

Comment: But your approach is not correct. I need this behavior because I try to implement wizzard on android and thus a user should not have a possibility to return back. Android team recommends to have clear behavior in case of back button.

Comment: Yury, post where the second activity is called.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Pavel Dudka below.

Comment: Guys, thanks to all. OnStop method is not called because of unknown reason in this activity. Can someone explain why the code in the first activity continues to execute after the second activity is started? I guess just after the startActivity in the first activity should be called onPause -> onStop methods, but I see that finish() is also executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you should call finish() for your first activity right after you send an intent. Something like:

```
...
startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
finish();
```

This will trigger onPause()->onStop()->onDestroy() chain for your first activity, so you can perform normal clean-up there

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I do not understand some things: 1. Why my onStop method is not called in this activity? 2. Can you explain why after starting new activity code in the previous continues to execute?

Comment: I believe it is because the os is free to destroy that activity on its own schedule.  There is nothing that requires it to destroy an activity as soon as it loses the foreground. Although, the onPause() method should be called right away after losing the foreground, and onStop shortly after.

Comment: @Yury Joel is right. I was struggling with the same problem before where I had a requirement to destroy an activity as soon as possible. However, Android OS does not guarantee onDestroy() to be called as soon as activity goes away of foreground. First of all OS will give priority to your second activity to get initialized and moved to idle state. Only after that your first activity will take onDestroy event.