# Why to call finish()

Tags: android, android-activity

I read [When finish() should be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656617/when-finish-should-be-called) and have little question why we called finsh() method, is there any criteria like if this happened then we call finish method.

Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### When to call finish()

In Android you call the `finish()` method on an activity when you are done with it, and it should be closed.

Quote below from the API;

> **public void finish ()**
>
> Added in API level 1 Call this when your activity is done and should
>   be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched
>   you via onActivityResult()

When you do this, your app will call the [`destroy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) method on your activity and fall back to the last Activity that is still open on the stack (go back a page).

I hope this helps.

- [Activity - Developers API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())